# Iteration to Recurssion

Tags: python-3.x

so myListToPyList(lst): takes lst, a MyList object and returns a Python list containing the same data

```
def myListToPyList(lst):
    return myListToPyListRec(lst.head)
```

here's my helper function:

```
def myListToPyListRec(node):
    if node == None:
        return 
    else:
        st1 = []
        st1.append(node.data)
        myListToPyListRec(node.next)
    return st1
```

it's not working correctly.

Now here is my iterative solution that works correctly:

```
    def myListToPyList(lst):
    """
    Takes a list and returns a python list containing
    the same data
    param; lst
    return; list
    """

    st1 = []
    curr = lst.head
    while curr != None:
        st1.append(curr.data)
        curr = curr.next
    return st1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current recursive code doesn't work because each time it gets called, it creates a new empty list, adds a single value to the list, then recurses (without passing the list along). This means that when the last item in the link list is being processed, the call stack will have `N` one-element Python lists (where `N` is the number of list nodes).

Instead, you should create the list just once, in your non-recursive wrapper function. Then pass it along through all of the recursion:

```
def myListToPyList(lst):
    result_list = []                          # create just one Python list object
    myListToPyListRec(lst.head, result_list)  # pass it to the recursive function
    return result_list                        # return it after it has been filled

def myListToPyListRec(node, lst):
    if node is not None              # the base case is to do nothing (tested in reverse)
        lst.append(node.data)                 # if node exists, append its data to lst
        myListToPyListRec(node.next, lst)     # then recurse on the next node
```

Because Python lists are mutable, we don't need to return anything in our recursive calls (`None` will be returned by default, but we ignore that). The list referred to by `result_list` in `myListToPyList` is the same object referred to by `lst` in each of the recursive calls to `myListToPyListRec`. As long as the recursive function mutates the object in place (e.g. with `append`) rather than rebinding it, they'll all see the same thing.

Note that recursion is going to be less eficient in Python than iteration, since function calls have more overhead than just updating a couple variables.

Answer (score 0):

A while loop is equivalent to tail recursion, and vice versa.  (One reason Python does not have automatic tail-call elimination is that the 'vice versa' part is rather easy.)  The tail recursion requires that you add an accumulator parameter to be returned in the base case.  Although I do not have a linked list for testing, I believe the following should work.  (If not, this is close.)  Python's default arguments make the helper either easier or unnecessary.

```
def myListToPyListRec(node, py_list=[]):
    if node
        py_list.append(node.data)
        return myListToPyListRec(node.next, py_list)
    else:
        return py_list
```